# Find single line comments in byte array

Tags: java, arrays

Is it possible to find instances of `//` in a line read from a file into a byte array and then "snip" from `//` to the end of the line out? I'm trying

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
int read;

while ((read = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < read; i++) 
    {
        if (buffer[i] == '//')
        {
            buffer = buffer[0:i];
        }
    }
}
```

but I'm getting `Invalid character constant` at `if (buffer[i] == '//')` on the `'//'` part. Am I doing something wrong, or is this just not possible?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using a BufferedReader?

Comment: Because '//' isn't a character, this is character '/'.

Comment: Is there a way to check for `//`?

Comment: I'm sure in single position of buffer will not be '//' because it's impossible.

Comment: Why are you reading strings as bytes in the first place? Use an appropriate reader that will read lines and use `indexOf()`. It looks to me like you're trying to write C code using Java

Answer (score 1):

Old-school solution

```
for (int i = 0; i < read-1; i++) 
    {
        (if (buffer[i] == '/') && (buffer[i+1]== '/'))
        {
            buffer = buffer[0:i];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`'` and `'` denote *one* character. Since `//` are two characters this does not work. One has to differentiate between a character and a string. Thus you have to individually check both positions in the byte array to confirm there are two successive `/`s.

Comment: Damn, there are some funny downvoters around. Can you please explain, so I can improve the answer?